# C++ bits operation. 6 integers into one unsigned long long

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

I would like to put 6 ints into one unsigned long long variable. Then, I would like to read these integers from long long variable bits range. I wrote something like this but it returns negative output

```
unsigned long long encode(int caller, int caller_zone,
int callee, int callee_zone,
int duration, int tariff) {

struct CallInfo
{
 int caller : 17;
 int caller_zone : 7;
 int callee : 17;
 int callee_zone : 7;
 int duration : 13;
 int tariff : 3;
};

CallInfo info = { caller, caller_zone, callee, callee_zone, duration, tariff};

cout << info.caller << endl;
cout << info.caller_zone << endl;   
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to use bit fields for this.

Comment: You code will only work properly if the inputs are unsigned and small enough.  If, for instance, caller_zone is >=128, it will "leak" into the space you are using for caller.

Comment: 6 32-bit integers do not fit into a 64-bit `unsigned long long`. You need to specify the ranges as well. Please edit the question with something like this: `caller is between 0 and XYZ, callee is between 0 and VWX, caller_zone is between 0 and ...`

Comment: are you sure `sizeof(long long int)` is large enough for `6*32` bits?

Comment: How to deal with mentioned leaks?

Comment: `caller << 47` may be undefined behaviour, since `47` is too large. You need something like `static_cast<unsigned long long int>(caller) << 47` etc.

Comment: How should I specify ranges?

Comment: Think. What they mean is that you should think how many bits you want for each variable (caller, caller_zone...) so that all together is <=64bit. The downsite is, you have to limit the numbers which can be stored together with the bit length

Comment: int caller - 17 bits, int caller_zone - 7 bits,
int callee - 17 bits, int callee_zone - 7 bits,
int duration - 13 bits, int tariff - 3 bits

Comment: edit added, but negative output

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to use bit fields for this, e.g.

```
struct CallInfo
{
    unsigned int caller : 17;
    unsigned int caller_zone : 7;
    unsigned int callee : 17;
    unsigned int callee_zone : 7;
    unsigned int duration : 13;
    unsigned int tariff : 3;
};
```

You would not really need an encode function, as you could just write, e.g.

```
CallInfo info = { /* ... initialise fields here ... */ };
```

and then access fields in the normal way:

```
info.caller = 0;
info.caller_zone = info.callee_zone;
// ...
```

Comment: You could do it yourself too... copy his code into your file, make a variable of type `info` instead of `unsigned long long` (for example `info foo;` and access the member like `foo.caller` (edit: ok, now my code is invalid. But i think you should understand it anyway)

Comment: I thought that any bitfield over 32b was sort of a crapshoot

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: That was the case before you had 64 bit types. A bitfield can only "shorten" a type, not "lengthen" it. So `unsigned long : 32` always works, but `unsigned int:17` might not. And `unsigned long : 33` was a problem, but now we can write `unsigned long long : 64`

Comment: @MSalters Didn'e we have 64b types on 32b architectures? (__uint64 on VS) Anyway, it's still something to watch out for as there is a lot of 32b code running around. Plus, now you've just pushed teh limit to 64b and if you need 65, you're sol. Right?

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: Not in the standard, and it was unspecified whether you could other types for bitfields. But note that `unsigned long long` has to be 64+ bits even on 32 bits systems (or 37 bits systems, the standard doesn't make assumptions here)

Comment: It sounds like you actually want *unsigned* ints for your various fields ? If that's the case then make the bit fields `unsigned int` and you should probably also use more appropriate types for the parameters to your encode function.

Comment: But I need to pass CallInfo to another function 'void info(unsigned long long u)'

Comment: Ideally just using `CallInfo` wherever you need this information (instead of `unsigned long long`), but if you have a function where you can't change the signature for some reason then either use a union of memcpy. You haven't really spelled out your actual requirements in the question in any detail so it's becoming quite time-consuming to have to keep guessing what it is that you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I cannot change signature, could you help with memcpy using in this case? I have tried something like this: 'memcpy(u, &info, sizeof(u));' but do not work...

Comment: Assuming `u` is a `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` then you probably just want `memcpy(&u, &info, sizeof(u));`.